# How do I install Cloudera CDH on 100 Node cluster without using Cloudera manager?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

How do I install Cloudera CDH on 100 Node cluster without using Cloudera manager? Installing and configuring CDH manually on each node in a cluster is a difficult task. What tools and technologies are used to automate the task in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDH supports both Parcel based and Package based installation. You can use Puppet/Chef these type of configuration management tools to do the package based install if you wish. However, the recommended way is to use Cloudera Manager to do Parcel-based installation. Cloudera Manager provides many features OOTB including monitoring, configuration versioning, wizard based security configuration, rolling upgrade, etc. If your reason of not using Cloudera Manager is because it is not open source, please note

1. There is a free version of CM (some enterprise features are not
   available)
2. CM is just a management tool. Your data are still stored
   on HDFS and your big data applications (hive scripts, spark/MapReduce
   applications, etc) still work on standard open source Hadoop
   platform and there is no vendor lock-in.

Comment: Thanks Lan for your answer.